# How to delay in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

the `.defer(5000)` is causing a `too much recursion` error in JavaScript.  How do I delay the execution by 5 seconds?

```
rotate: function () {
  if (!paused) {
    this.show(counter);

    counter = counter + 1;

    if (counter === Spire.Rotator.data.items.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }

    Spire.Rotator.rotate().defer(5000);
    //$.proxy(Spire.Rotator.rotate, Spire.Rotator).defer(delay);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This entire line:

```
Spire.Rotator.rotate().defer(5000);
```

is wrong. Because of the parentheses just after `rotate`, your function is immediately calling itself over and over again (infinite recursion). Removing the parentheses will fix that problem, but the code will probably not work. To fix the code, use the browser's [`window.setTimeout` method](https://web.archive.org/web/20120518065851/https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout), which accepts a function and a delay (in milliseconds) as two arguments:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    Spire.Rotator.rotate();
}, 5000);
```

Why not just `setTimeout(Spire.Rotator.rotate, 5000);`? The reason is that `this` in that function would be `window` rather than `Spire.Rotator`. (There's [plenty of information](https://web.archive.org/web/20160410132421/https://justin.harmonize.fm/index.php/2009/09/an-introduction-to-javascripts-this/) on the Internet about this.) Why not `setTimeout("Spire.Rotator.rotate()", 5000);`? That's a quite dated (deprecated) way to use the method that suffers from the same [pitfalls of eval](https://ericlippert.com/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/), a function that some JavaScript programmers including Douglas Crockford recommend not using.

Answer (score 3):

Simply substitute this:

```
Spire.Rotator.rotate().defer(5000);
```

With this:

```
setTimeout(Spire.Rotator.rotate, 5000);
```

[`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) is javascript's native way of executing some Javascript code after a specified amount of time.

Comment: Don't use strings as parameter to setTimeout. It's valid but prone to quoting hell and is also slow. Use a function instead: `setTimeout(Spire.Rotator.rotate, 5000)`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in your code, defer() never gets called. Assuming the rotate method you're defining is for the Spire.Rotator object what happens is:

```
rotate() calls rotate() calls rotate() calls rotate() .... [to infinity]
```

After `infinity` number of calls the return value of the `infinitieth` call will then call the defer method. But you have to wait for `infinity` calls to happen which takes `eternity` seconds to complete.

What you need is [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout).